# IdentityServer4 handle multiple facebook AppIds for tenancy

Tags: asp.net-core, identityserver4, facebook-oauth

We are adding tenancy to our IdentityServer4 (https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4) implementation.  So far everything is good.  AspIdentity appends a prefix to the username based on the hostname on the request ie. sso.domain1.com and sso.domain2.com create tenancy in the identity database.  The external oauth for google works fine as well as google's API console allows multiple websites to access the same AppId.  Facebook, on the other hand, only allows one domain per AppId.  The external providers are registered during the application startup so this presents a problem as we need to determine the correct Facebook AppId to use per request based on the hostname.

Any suggestions on the appropriate way to handle this scenario?  I tried having all Facebook AppIds registered at startup and letting the login page UI determine which Facebook button to make visible.  IdentityServer threw an exception for this as it doesn't allow multiple providers with the same scheme name.

Is there somewhere in the pipeline we could overload to pass in the Request host and change the External Provider AppId per request?

**Update 1:**

Based on McGuireV10 answer I was able to get closer to the goal.  The issue now is that in the event I can set the ClientId and ClientSecret option properties, but that doesn't change the Uri that was generated for the RequestUri property.  Should I be doing it a different way or do I need to rebuild the context so it regenerates the RedirectUri?  I've been trying to go through Microsoft's Security source code, but haven't been able to find this yet.  Ideas?

```
services.AddAuthentication().AddFacebook(externalAuthentication.Name, options => {
                options.SignInScheme = externalAuthentication.SignInScheme;
                options.ClientId = externalAuthentication.DefaultClientId;
                options.ClientSecret = externalAuthentication.DefaultClientSecret;
                options.RemoteAuthenticationTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5);
                options.Events = new Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OAuth.OAuthEvents {
                    OnRedirectToAuthorizationEndpoint = context => {
                        var tenancySetting = GetExternalAuthProviderForRequest(context.Request, externalAuthentication);
                        if (tenancySetting != null) {
                            context.Options.ClientId = tenancySetting.ClientId;
                            context.Options.ClientSecret = tenancySetting.ClientSecret;
                        }

                        context.RedirectUri = BuildChallengeUrl(context);
                        context.HttpContext.Response.Redirect(context.RedirectUri);
                        return Task.FromResult(0);
                    }
                };
            });
```

Update 2:

It is working now. I'm sure there must be a better way to do it, but I took the easy way out for now. I grabbed Microsoft's source code (https://github.com/aspnet/Security) and after looking through that I'm pretty sure that the HandleChallengeAsync method (Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OAuth.OAuthHandler) is being called in the pipeline prior to entering the RedirectToAuthorizationEndpoint event.  HandleChallegeAsync takes care of building the RedirectUri property on the context.  There doesn't seem to be an existing method to rebuild the RedirectUri in Microsoft's code so I copied out their code for BuildChallegeUrl and used that to rebuild the RedirectUri.  I updated the sample code to reflect this change.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding an [`OpenIdConnectEvents`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.authentication.openidconnect.openidconnectevents) handler for the `OnRedirectToIdentityProvider` event and replace the `ClientId` and `ClientSecret` properties there, but I don't know if that will confuse Identity Server in some way. I don't have a similar use-case so I haven't tried this specific thing myself, but I intercept other events and change the protocol properties without any problems. I also don't know if you'd still need to set the id and secret on the `options` property itself, but that's easy enough to test. It would look something like this:

```cs
services.AddAuthentication()
    .AddFacebook("Facebook", options =>
    {
        options.Events = new OpenIdConnectEvents
        {
            OnRedirectToIdentityProvider = context =>
            {
                context.ProtocolMessage.ClientId = "abc";
                context.ProtocolMessage.ClientSecret = "xyz";
                return Task.FromResult<object>(null);
            }
        };
        options.SignInScheme = IdentityServerConstants.ExternalCookieAuthenticationScheme;
        // you probably don't need these:
        options.ClientId = oauth2config["FacebookId"];
        options.ClientSecret = oauth2config["FacebookSecret"];
    });
```

Obviously you'd need something more complex and implementation-specific to actually figure out the client etc.

Comment: That put me on the right track, but some items are off. I'm using aspnet core 2.0. I'll post what I have below so far.

Comment: Ah can you share what you found out - I'm having this exact same issue!